# Adding pyrocms to existing website

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, content-management-system, pyrocms

Unfortunately I'm months into a project and now the client is requesting a cms based option to edit a few pages on the fly. Now I'm totally knew to pyrocms but from what I've been reading it's not your traditional cms.

The current site already uses codeigniter so I'm not sure how this will effect it.

Since the site is pretty much done except for the few pages that now need cms editing capabilities is pyrocms something I can add an use to control the information on these pages? The only thing I'm needing out of it is the page editing capabilities, blogs, modules, comments, add/ delete pages are not needed.

Using an already made page is it possible to get pyrocms to control the text that the page uses? with other cms's you can generally just point the template to the page.

Not sure how this will work with routing, considering http://site.com/editpage and pyro would be installed as something like http://site.com/admin. Does it have the backwards compatibility to exit outside it's directory or will I have to target the database manually and pull the information out and display it accordingly.

Comment: Pyro is not a good solution for adding CMS-esque capabilities to a few pages inside an existing application. And it's also being moved off of the CI framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cryodes reaction is correct. I suggest you create your own control panel thingy by creating a custom login section using ION auth: https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth

Another simpler option is to create an admin folder into your sites root and just install PyroCMS in it. Set the routers in Pyro to the PyroCMS admin area and then use the backend with its login to create articles. Then in your CI application connect to Pyro's database and grab the articles from it.